# Boost asio io_service - what happens is queue is full

Tags: boost-asio

I am trying to understand how the boost::asio::io_service works. Here is what I think -

An instance of the boost::asio::io_service internally implements an event based queue, such that events posted to the queue are handled by threads implementing the io_service::run() method. The advantage of using this as against a normal queue is that io_service is asynchronous, so there is no need to waste CPU cycles polling for events in the queue.

If the above is correct, then what would happen if there are fewer threads available to handle the work (event) and the rate at which work is posted to io_service is too high.

At some point, when this queue becomes full, would the post block?

My intention is to have a non-blocking post against the io_service. If the post isn't successful, I want to discard the work event.

Looking for some advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The queue is bounded by available resources only. My assumption is it will throw (e.g. `bad_alloc`) when out of resources, but things will probably have "stopped working" for you before that time.

This is because limits on number of threads, open files, sockets etc. are usually lower, and even if not, the amount of work will usually clog so badly that you'll stop the program (because it's not working).

Recap: In the unlikely event that you do all your io_service work on *n* threads and the other *m* threads are still available to load tasks on the queue, I expect things to break with an exception.